# GhostScript render without text

Tags: c#-4.0, ghostscript

I would like to know, сan GhostScript render pdf on image (such as jpeg) without text? If not, advise the free library for .net, that it will make.

Sorry for my English. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by 'render without text' ? Do you mean that you want all the content of a PDF page rendered to a format which doesn;t contain text (such as JPEG), or do you mean you want all the content of a PDF page *except* the text rendered, to a file format such as JPEG.

Its possible to elide the text, but its not a command line switch or anything like that, because its pretty hard to see why you want to do this.

If you really  do want to do it, then your best bet is to modify the text handling procedures in the PDF interpreter, I would suggest that you don't alter the processing but set the text rendering mode to mode 3 (neither stroke nor fill) to prevent any problems with the current point not being correct.

Comment: I want all the content of a PDF page except the text rendered, to a file format such as JPEG. =) Thank's!

Comment: The only way to do that with Ghostscript is to override the text rendering routines, these are defined in /ghostpdl/gs/Resource/Init/pdf_ops.ps. As I said above I would suggest setting the text rendering mode to 3 (possibly a simple '3 Tr' at the start of the routine would be sufficient.